# Custom Jekyll 404 page is not working on Heroku

Tags: heroku, http-status-code-404, jekyll

I have a Jekyll site deployed to Heroku. I have created a custom 404 error page in `source/404.html` file. The page can be found at `mydomain.com/404/`. But when I try to go to pages which don't exist, the custom 404 page doesn't work. And instead I get a blank, default Heroku error page.

What can be a reason for that? Note that a permalink for the page doesn't have an html extension. Can this be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding a permalink to the YAML front matter?

```
permalink: /404.html
```

also I have read that the 404 page is specific to GitHub pages, but worth a try

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the [Heroku official Jekyll setup](https://blog.heroku.com/jekyll-on-heroku), you should use 2 buildpacks :

- heroku/ruby
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static

The latter allow a **static.json** configuration file (at the root of your project) to customize nginx. The documentation tells you [how to add custom error pages](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static#custom-error-pages).

In your case, the **static.json** file should contain :

```
{
  ...
  "error_page": "404.html",
  ...
}
```